# How to Star a Topic on GitHub with API?

Tags: github, github-api, github-api-v3, github-api-v4

Star a topic can be done on the website. But how to do the same operation via GitHub API v3 or v4? I read through the reference but got no clues.

Answer (score 0):

For the v3 REST API it's documented at [Star a repository for the authenticated user](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/activity#star-a-repository-for-the-authenticated-user)

The curl example is:

```sh
curl \
  -X PUT \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/user/starred/octocat/hello-world
```

But this doesn't show how to insert your token, so you actually need something more like:

```sh
curl \
  -X PUT \
  -H "Authorization: token $GITHUB_API_TOKEN" \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/user/starred/octocat/hello-world
```

Where GITHUB_API_TOKEN has been previously set like:

```sh
GITHUB_API_TOKEN="ghp_16C7e42F292c6912E7710c838347Ae178B4a"
```

Per comments to this earlier question [how to star a repo with github api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35828267/how-to-star-a-repo-with-github-api) make sure that the token used has the correct permissions to do the starring, which means having the repo scope (or at least repo_public) enabled.

I'd also love to know how to do this with the v4 GraphQl API.

Comment: I mean Topic, not the Repo